# How do I set up Paypal automated checkout?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We have our own custom products that we sell. We are entering into a partnership where someone will be using their website to send customers to us. Their customers will pay with our Paypal button on their website, once we receive payment we ship out the product and pay a portion of the profits to them. On paper this sounds good but we have no idea how to execute it. How will we know the sale came from their website? How do we set this up without them needing access to our Paypal account?

Any ideas on where to start? Thank you, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please, hire a developer to set this up for you. As it is, you're basically asking people to complete a project for you completely for free - that isn't what this site is about.

Comment: I hired a PHP developer. He doesn't know where to start either. What should I do? Help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure he knows what he's doing? I don't want to be nasty, but if a client hired me and I had to ask them to post on a site like this because I didn't know what to do I'd expect to be fired...

Comment: He's never worked with Paypal before. I use him for other things with the website. He works with APIs but not IPNs. He's cheap. He just would like to know where to get started or where to learn.